# Installing Google SDK in Debian 10?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, debian, runtime-error, warnings, google-cloud-sdk

I am following instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get) to install Google Cloud SDK:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

but in updating APT such that

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ftp.debian.org/debian unstable InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental InRelease                                                         
Hit:3 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                     
Get:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease [6,337 B]                      
Err:5 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
Hit:4 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6A030B21BA07F4FB
E: The repository 'https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

and in adding the key

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

with Debian version

```
$ cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l
```

**How can I properly install Google Cloud SDK in Debian 10?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PO's Google support manual [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-apt-get) is outdated. The new thread [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-debian-ubuntu) fixed the issue:

```
# Add the Cloud SDK distribution URI as a package source
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list

# Import the Google Cloud Platform public key
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -

# Update the package list and install the Cloud SDK
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (from within debian VM or container):

1. `apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl python`
2. `curl sdk.cloud.google.com -L | bash`

Exit the VM (or container) and access it again.

3. `gcloud init`

And you are done.